# embedded jetty web app server

Tags: maven-2, embedded-jetty

I am trying to build a web app with **built in web server** and found a source doucumentation [here](https://gist.github.com/1054400).
this tutorial uses maven to build initial project structure with **required** setup.
the command used is

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven.publicstaticvoidmain.net/archetype-catalog.xml  -DarchetypeGroupId=net.publicstaticvoidmain -DarchetypeArtifactId=embedded-jetty-archetype

however running this command gives the error

```
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://maven.publicstaticvoidmain.net/archetype-catalog.xml
```

i am new to maven so unable to figure out the actual problem what i got is that the catalog is not found in the global repository.
what could be the proper fix for this?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your [Here] link is not working.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar - updated the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya, the catalog is not present where you are pointing the url.
however, what you want to do can be found [here](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/08/23/war-less-java-web-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a non-functional site  http://maven.publicstaticvoidmain.net.

The example if ever it was working is not suitable now as the above site is defunct.

Are you looking for something related to standalone web app - http://pineapplesoftware.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-make-standalone-web-application.html